# how to make Flex Authentication persistance?

Tags: php, apache-flex, session, authentication, zend-amf

Hi
  I am using php on server side, once I authenticate flex channel set and then reload the application by refreshing the page , I again need to authenticate channel set by login in and calling cs.login(username,password);

I want flex application to check when it loads weather user is already authenticated or not .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shared objects, the Flash version of a cookie.  Also, if you're using server side sessions, reloading the page should not reset the browser cookie which ties your front end to the back end session.  So, you could always ping the server to see if the user authenticated there.

Comment: ok so I using shared object checked that session cookie is present but now how will I do channel set authentication programmatic (channelSet.login(username,password)) which require a username and password both of which are not in cookie ??

Comment: I guess I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you should share some code.  As best I understand it, from the Flex documentation, channelSets are implemented for BlazeDS and LiveCycle only.  The ChannelSet class has no login() method, nor does HTTPService or RemoteObject.